# Confusion in "mask bits"

Tags: encoding-scheme, number-formats

This is the question:

> By definition of the IEEE754 standard, 32-bit floating point numbers
>   are represented as  follows:
>
> S (1 bit)  E (8 bits)  M (23 bits)  S: Sign bit  E: Exponent  M:
>   Mantissa
>
> Which of the following is the correct “mask bits” in hexadecimal to be
>   used for  extracting only the exponent part of the above format?
>   Here, “mask bits” means a bit  pattern which is logically ANDed
>   withthe 32-bit floating point value.
>
> a) 107FFFFF  b)  7F800000  c)  FF100000  d) FF800000

The given answer is b : 7F800000, but i have no idea why, can anyone give me an explanation, i'm greatly appreciated!

Is that because :

7F800000 = 0**111 1111 1**000 (8)

While others answer contain more `"1"` in binary format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bitwise `AND` a number in this format with `7F800000` you get:

```
    SEEEEEEEEMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
AND 01111111100000000000000000000000

  = 0EEEEEEEE00000000000000000000000
```

Everything gets set to `0` except the exponent. Yes, it is necessary for the correct answer to have 8 ones, but it is also necessary that they are in the correct positions. `00007F80` would not be correct because it would result in:

```
    SEEEEEEEEMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
AND 00000000000000000111111110000000

  = 00000000000000000MMMMMMMM0000000
```